# Copy a database using mongo driver

Tags: mongodb, c#-4.0

I have the following code:

```
 mongoServer.CopyDatabase(mongoDatabaseName, partitionName.Replace("__", string.Empty));
 mongoServer.DropDatabase(mongoDatabaseName);
```

I obtain the following exception "NotImplementedException - The method or operation is not implemented."

How is it possible? I've wronged something? How can I copy my database?

Comment: The driver is MongoDB.Driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is correct as the `CopyDatabase` method isn't implemented.  See the [JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-554) for the history of the issue.

Instead, you need to directly invoke the `'copydb'` command via a call to `RunCommand` on the `admin` database like is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14518513/1259510).  So something like:

```
var adminDB = Server.GetDatabase("admin");
var command = new CommandDocument(new List<BsonElement> {
    new BsonElement("copydb", 1),
    new BsonElement("fromhost", "localhost"),
    new BsonElement("fromdb", mongoDatabaseName),
    new BsonElement("todb", partitionName.Replace("__", string.Empty))
});
var result = adminDB.RunCommand(command);
```